# expect script works fine standalone not from bash script

Tags: bash, expect

I am running a expect script,which login to a server check if iptables running and return the log file of the status. There is a hostfile also given with server list and password, expect is being called from a shell script which it sending correct parameter; running those parameters individually i can execute the expect script too, but it is just not working in tandem. 
the hostfile below:

```
cat hostfile
10.20.52.167|abcdef
10.20.52.138|zyxwvu
```

the shell script being executed:

```
cat iptables
#! /bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
while read line
do
ipaddress=`echo $line | awk -F'|' '{print $1}'`
password=`echo $line | awk -F'|' '{print $2}'`
echo "./testcase_3 $ipaddress \"$password\" "
sleep 5
done < hostfile
```

And lastly the expect script:

```
cat testcase_3
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#! /bin/bash

set timeout 60
set host [lindex $argv 0]
set password [lindex $argv 1]
log_user 1
set user subhasish
set logfile output.txt
foreach host $host password $password {
spawn ssh $user@$host
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "$password\r"
sleep 2
expect "$"
send -- "sudo su\r"
expect -gl {*password for subhasish:*}
send -- "$password\r"
expect "#"
send -- "service iptables status\r"
log_file /home/subhasish/output.log
expect "#"
log_file
}
send -- "exit\r";
send -- "exit\r";
exit 0
```

I have got no clue where it is going wrong, please help. The iptables script sends argument like "./testcase_3 *.*.*.* "******" ", which if i run in the commandline works expected by creating output.log. Nothing happens however if i run the iptables script directly...

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell because as you're posted, `iptables` does not invoke the expect script. To debug the expect script, add this near the top: `exp_internal 1`

Since the shell's read command can grab multiple words if the right field separator is provided, I would write the bash script like this:

```sh
while IFS='|' read ipaddress password; do
    echo "./testcase_3 $ipaddress \"$password\""
    ./testcase_3 "$ipaddress" "$password"
    sleep 5
done < hostfile
```